# How do I consolidate multiple entries into a new value in microsoft access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to aggregate the Total Sum of [Award] and Count of [Counter] for different [PO Types]. Is there a way to group all the existing PO Types into one value "SRM" within the same query?

The end result I want is one record: SRM |  $37,823,372.89 | 1732

[image]
Here is the current SQL:

```
SELECT tblSRMECC.[PO Type], Sum(tblSRMECC.Award) AS SumOfAward, Count(tblSRMECC.[Counter (PO)]) AS 
[CountOfCounter (PO)]
FROM tblSRMECC
GROUP BY [PO Type]
HAVING (((tblSRMECC.[PO Type])<>"AutoPO" And (tblSRMECC.[PO Type])<>"Fixed Price Catalog"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is to amend your existing query to add a `UNION` that does the subtotal. Something like this as your SQL:

```
SELECT 0 AS DataSortOrder, tblSRMECC.[PO Type], Sum(tblSRMECC.Award) AS SumOfAward, Count(tblSRMECC.[Counter (PO)]) AS 
[CountOfCounter (PO)]
FROM tblSRMECC
GROUP BY [PO Type]
HAVING (((tblSRMECC.[PO Type])<>"AutoPO" And (tblSRMECC.[PO Type])<>"Fixed Price Catalog"))
UNION SELECT 1,"SRM",Sum(tblSRMECC.Award), Count(tblSRMECC.[Counter (PO)]) 
FROM tblSRMECC
HAVING (((tblSRMECC.[PO Type])<>"AutoPO" And (tblSRMECC.[PO Type])<>"Fixed Price Catalog"))
ORDER BY 1,2
```

The extra column that I have added, DataSortOrder, is just to make sure that the total appears after the individual totals.

If you only want to show the overall total, then you can just use the part of the query that I added:

```
SELECT "SRM",Sum(tblSRMECC.Award), Count(tblSRMECC.[Counter (PO)]) 
FROM tblSRMECC
HAVING (((tblSRMECC.[PO Type])<>"AutoPO" And (tblSRMECC.[PO Type])<>"Fixed Price Catalog"))
```

Regards,

Comment: this worked. Ideally I would want the query to just show SRM total and award. However, I can always just make another query off yours to show that.
Thanks!

Comment: Additional SQL added to just show the total as one record.